# Display number of files in the folder using PHP

Tags: php, html

I've this simple script for displaying all the images in the folder.

```
 <?php 

 foreach(glob("".$filePath."/*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,gif,GIF,png,PNG}",GLOB_BRACE) as $images) 
{
$filecount = count(glob("".$filePath."/*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,gif,GIF,png,PNG}",GLOB_BRACE));
if ($filecount >1)
    {
echo "<img   width='75' height='auto' style='margin-right: 3px; border:1px solid #dddddd' alt='".$row["caption"] ."' src=\"".$images."\">";
    }
else
    {
echo "<img   width='200' height='auto' style='margin-right: 3px; border:1px solid #dddddd' alt='".$row["caption"] ."' src=\"".$images."\">";
    }

}

 ?>
```

I want to display number of files in the  folder.Giving below what i tried..My problem is that this shows the number of files before each image.

```
if ($filecount >1)
{
echo '' . $user . ' ' .'added ' . ' ' . $filecount . ' ' . 'new photos';
echo "<img width='75' height='auto' style='margin-right: 3px;  alt='".$row["caption"] ."' src=\"".$images."\">";
}
```

How can I show number of files before the group of images displayed?

Comment: What Language is this, you should add a tag

Comment: Sorry about that.this is php.I've added the tag.

Comment: Perhaps do a foreach loop to get the count of the files, then print it before your main foreach loop

Comment: If that does work for you, let me know and I'll submit it as an answer

Comment: Sure.I'm working on it.thanks again..

Comment: @ BenVlodgi can you please just show me how the code will be?I'm confused a bit.I'm newbie to php..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to display the number of files only after it has collected them.
You can do it by declaring the filecount variable before the loop, then you need to count and sum the value everytime the loop goes to the next result, and eventually display the total number of files.
Here is how the code should be written:

```
<?php 
$filecount = 0;

foreach(glob("".$filePath."/*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,gif,GIF,png,PNG}",GLOB_BRACE) as $images) 
{
    $tempFileCount = count(glob("".$filePath."/*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,gif,GIF,png,PNG}",GLOB_BRACE))
    $filecount += $tempFileCount;
    if ($tempFileCount > 1)
    {
        echo "<img   width='75' height='auto' style='margin-right: 3px; border:1px solid #dddddd' alt='".$row["caption"] ."' src=\"".$images."\">";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<img   width='200' height='auto' style='margin-right: 3px; border:1px solid #dddddd' alt='".$row["caption"] ."' src=\"".$images."\">";
    }
}

if($filecount > 1)
{
    echo '' . $user . ' ' .'added ' . ' ' . $filecount . ' ' . 'new photos';
}

?>
```

Comment: I found an error in this line and corrected it.
 $filecount += $tempFileCount;  I changed this line to  $filecount = $tempFileCount; and it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and sorry, I didn't get the chance to test this code.

Answer (score 0):

First create a function that returns all images as array. This will throw an exception if there is an error with the [glob](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) php function (will mostly never happen, but worth it to know it when it happens). The function will give the sense that the code is a little bit cleaner.

```
<?php
function getAllImagesOnDirectory($directory) {
     $imagesArray = glob("".$filePath."/*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,gif,GIF,png,PNG}",GLOB_BRACE);
     if(!is_array($imagesArray)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("There is a problem getting images on directory " . $directory);
     }
     
     return $imagesArray;
}


//Then we call this function to get all the images.
$allImagesOnFilePath = getAllImagesOnDirectory($filePath);
$numberOfImages = count($allImagesOnFilePath);

     
if($numberOfImages > 0) { 
     echo '<p>' . $user . ' added ' . $numberOfImages . ' new photos</p>';
     //If the number of images is more than 0 then traverse all the images and echo them
     foreach($allImagesOnFilePath as $oneImage) {
        echo "<img style='max-width:100%;height:auto;margin-right: 3px; border:1px solid #dddddd' alt='".$row["caption"] ."' src=\"".$oneImage."\">";
     }
}
else { 
     //The user has no uploaded images
     echo '<p>' . $user . ' has not added new photos yet :(</p>';
}
```

This way we can use the `$numberOfImages` before using `foreach` and thus doing what you requested.
We also here use the style attribute to apply width and height to images. See this article to see how to make autoresizable images: http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images